# Grab the value of this input box on 'keyup' event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of the input box that has just 'received' the keyup event - can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
$('#ajax_basket').on('keyup','input',function(event) {    
    console.log('keyup');

    console.log( event.val() );

   });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `this` like this:

```
console.log( $(this).val() );
```

or just `console.log(this.value);`, otherwise you should use `event.target.value`

More info about [**event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) on MDN.

Comment: oh my gosh.. so simple thank you sergio, my eyes need rest :-) will accept in 12mins